# creating a web api wrapper around an existing API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017, authorize.net

Authorize.NET offers a [very thorough SDK.](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet).

You can simply install it in your solution:

```
Install-Package AuthorizeNet
```

We need service(s) to wrap all the capabilities of the AuthorizeNet API.

For simplicity, let's say that the API exposes the following methods:

```
public bool Pay(TransactionModel trans);
public bool Decline(Guid id);
public bool Refund(Guid id);
```

We have easy access to these methods from our own solution controller methods. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool PayAuthNet([FromBody] AuthnetTransModel model)
{
   TransactionModel localTransModel = CreateLocalAuthModel(model);
   var authNet = new AuthorizeNet();
   return authNet.Pay(localTransModel);
}
```

However, the API library is pretty vast that Authorize.NET exposes:

[image]

Assuming that we want to wrap these controllers, each into its own microservice (would like feedback on this approach), **Is there an easier way to wrap every one of these APIs, forcing the client to go through our wrapper service, rather than allowing them to hit Authorize.NET directly?**

Comment: Isn't that API already a wrapper? Why do we need extra layer on top of that?

Comment: because my boss said that we do. we want to allow clients to use authorizenet but through a very "controlled" mechanism, and we want to control what each client can access etc, that is why we need a wrapper

Comment: Wow that is rather broad. Just off the top of my head you could try to create a convention based on the exposed API and route/funnel commands through one point. But I think that much work is not worth the effort IMO.

Comment: Doesn't seem too impractical if you use Roslyn

Comment: @johnny5 can you elaborate on how roslyn can be useful fo rthis?

Comment: @Nkosi can you give me an example?

Comment: Can you just add reference to Authorize.NET.dll and make a call to controller directly from your wrapper API?

Comment: @T.S. can you elaborate on your suggestion/?

Comment: you're hosting 3rd party tool, Authorize.NET. Right now, you install it and run it. It has controllers, it is full blown Web API project. Instead of running it directly in website, you reference the DLL it has, and you use the public methods, like `GetcustomerPaymentcontroller.Get(...)` in your web api. This way, you expose only methods you want. It may not be easy as their controllers might be marked with attributes for security etc.  you can also look what their controllers calling into. May be you can just reference another library, which they call (if exists)

Comment: I don't understand how that's different than my approach listed in the question

Comment: @nkosi why the .. did you delete your answer

Comment: another approach, that I thought in fact was your approach, is to call their intrAnet WEB API from your internet web api. So, this approach is to "soft wrap"

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I wasn't sure if it would meet your requirements. I can undelete it if you want.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Use roslyn / reflection to iterate over the Authorize.Net Dll and automatically Generate microservices based on there parameters

Comment: Or you just wanted to wrap it and and a layer of security, I know there are a few frameworks that can easily generate dynamic controllers

Comment: @johnny5 im sorry could you please give an example of a library

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' sorry they only work with a base class, which I don't think you will be able to generically create, since each method will have different parameters

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Why do you need a wrapper? If you don't want to use Roslyn, Why don't you just create a permission filter, to limit access to the existing API?

Comment: @johnny5 again, i'm still not clear on what you mean by using roslyn

Comment: Roslyn is the .Net compiler platform which allows your to read and write code.  You can use it to read the authorize api and automatically generate controllers

Comment: Can you point to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is meant as an simple explanation because it is too long for a comment.

Will be using Pseudo code to demonstrate wrapping the  `AuthorizeNet`

Using the example provided in the OP

```
[HttpPost]
public bool PayAuthNet([FromBody] AuthnetTransModel model)
{
   TransactionModel localTransModel = CreateLocalAuthModel(model);
   var authNet = new AuthorizeNet();
   return authNet.Pay(localTransModel);
}
```

First the naming convention. Similar to how MVC finds controller based on the naming convention like how `Name/Action` maps to `NameController.Action`

```
PayAuthNet     --> AuthorizeNet.Pay
DeclineAuthNet --> AuthorizeNet.Decline
RefundAuthNet  --> AuthorizeNet.Refund
```

And then using reflection the method argument type can be determined and a mapping function similar to how AutoMapper works would convert the provided model `AuthnetTransModel` to the expected `TransactionModel` argument for the function.

Hypothetically you can use expression trees to get away from magic strings

```
public class BillingConroller : ApiController {    
    [HttpPost]
    public bool PayAuthNet([FromBody] AuthnetTransModel model) {
       return authorizeNetWrapper.Execute<BillingConroller>(c => c.PayAuthNet(model));
    }    
}
```

Which internally would inspect the expression tree to extract the information needed to map and execute the matching wrapped API

```
From expression tree:
    Method being invoked:  PayAuthNet
    Argument provider:     AuthnetTransModel 
After applying convention:
    Found matching method: AuthorizeNet.Pay
    Expected argument:     TransactionModel
Construct command
    Create instance of TransactionModel and copy properties from provided model
    Invoke => authNet.Pay(localTransModel)
```